# Custom Facebook chat message template?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

Seems it is not possible to add custom message template to Facebook Chat, or do I miss something?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/templates#available_templates

I would use a template where user can express the importance of things, and can reorder rows in a list.

How could I impelement it?

Comment: You can not create your own at this time. As for reordering items, I can't think of any other way than implementing that in a rather clumsy fashion via buttons, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/templates/button

Comment: I guess I can not add a hamburger button, or HTML Drag and Drop API in that button, right? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: No, you can only use the pre-defined button types. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/buttons